# How to write a Dockerfile for a python project with dependencies Caffe, OpenCV

Tags: python, docker

How can I build my Docker image with a number of dependencies like `Berkeley Caffe` and `OpenCV`.

Here's my Dockerfile :

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install \ python-pip python-virtualenv tesseract-ocr poppler-utils

RUN python -m virtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python /opt/venv

#Install dependencies:
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN . /opt/venv/bin/activate && pip install -r requirements.txt

#Install caffe -cpu only
#compile caffe localy 
#install all req of caffe
#run all make commands and also run make pycaffe

#set the python path

#Run
$ cd API
$ ../bin/gunicorn --pythonpath "/opt/venv/caffe/python" -b localhost:5000 app
```

Comment: Do you have a recipe for building the extra dependencies outside of Docker, that you could translate into `RUN` instructions?  Or are these things that you could install using a third-party APT repository (or something like an Ubuntu PPA)?

Comment: Two generic comments: you don't need a virtual environment inside an isolated Docker container, and it's okay to `pip install` things into the "system" python; your final `gunicorn` command needs to listen on 0.0.0.0, not `localhost`, or the service will be unreachable from outside the container.

Comment: take a look at the already existing caffe docker images 
 this ( https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/docker/cpu/Dockerfile ) and this ( https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/docker/gpu/Dockerfile )
 you can copy things from them and use them in your dockerfile